# How to solve BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe in Python 3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

From `file1` I am calling `file2` using `os.popen("python file2.py")`, in `file2` I am reading csv file into a dataframe below is the code:

```
dataset = read_csv('dataset.csv',encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```

and again I am writing content of dataframe to the csv file. 
While reading and writing the file I am getting error: `BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`.

What should I do to solve it? please suggest. I am using python 3.6 in linux.
Thank you in advance.